# Drop shadow renders without transparency

Tags: android, android-xml, android-drawable, dropshadow

In [this project](https://bitbucket.org/tbsprs/altglas/src/2b187bbc25118c698fc8aac377e163c3f8f25719/?at=feature%2Fdrop-shadow) (*feature/drop-shadow* branch) I am trying to add a **drop shadow** above a view container. Therefore, I defined the following shape ([*drawable/shadow_above*](https://bitbucket.org/tbsprs/altglas/src/2b2dadc092efc781e619f64d229355a9fbc28230/app/src/main/res/drawable/shadow_above.xml?at=feature/drop-shadow)):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <gradient
            android:startColor="#20000000"
            android:endColor="@android:color/transparent"
            android:angle="90">
    </gradient>
</shape>
```

This is then used in the layout file ([*container_infos.xml*](https://bitbucket.org/tbsprs/altglas/src/2b2dadc092efc781e619f64d229355a9fbc28230/app/src/main/res/layout/container_infos.xml?at=feature/drop-shadow)) as follows:

```
<View
    android:background="@drawable/shadow_above"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="4dp"/>
```

The screenshot shows the result. For some reason the drop shadow looks awful. There is **no transparency**. What am I doing wrong? Feel free to send a pull request to my open source project.

[image: Awful drop shadow]

---

## Solution using a RelativeLayout

I managed to get the desired result by using a RelativeLayout in *fragment_map.xml*:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              tools:context=".ui.MainActivity">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/map_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            tools:background="@android:color/holo_purple"/>

        <View
            android:background="@drawable/shadow_above"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@id/map_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="4dp"/>

    </RelativeLayout>

    <include
        layout="@layout/container_infos"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

There might be room for optimization.

Comment: Your view with gradient is in a LinearLayout. Are you sure that the view is actually above something else? I guess you mean to have the shadow over the map? If not then your angle of gradient is pointing the wrong way. At the bottom it is gray, at the top it is transparent (with your background shining through). So double check that you have placed the view with gradient where it needs to be.

Comment: True. It is actually in the wrong place. The info box slides up and moves the map with it. Currently the drop shadow view merges with the default background. - Therefore, the shadow has to be placed above the map. I feel like this has to be done programmatically. Should be a "layer" above the `map_container` in  [*fragment_map.xml*](https://bitbucket.org/tbsprs/altglas/src/2b2dadc092efc781e619f64d229355a9fbc28230/app/src/main/res/layout/fragment_map.xml?at=feature/drop-shadow).

Answer (score 0):

as far as I see you should give map_container_infos_layout a negative top margin of the size 4dp and it should look better

Comment: Sorry, this does not work for me. I set `android:layout_marginTop="-4dp"` for `map_container_infos_layout`. The underlying background is the background color of the `container_infos` not the map. - I found a solution using a RelativeLayout - I will post it in my question.